# What does it mean when the default activity of an app is android.app.Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, juce

This is a `AndroidManifests.xml` for a non default Android project generated by Projuce ([juce.com](http://juce.com))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0"
          package="com.yourcompany.NewProject">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"
                    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.rmsl.juce.JuceApp" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
    <activity android:name="android.app.Activity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
              android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

You can see that the default activity is `<activity android:name="android.app.Activity"`. How can this be the default activity? What is launched then?

This is the entire project: https://github.com/lzunsec/juce_example_android/tree/faf9e3362b7e7e56ae8918f31196e35a3e6dadca/NewProject

It has no java files, almost no C++ files, so I do not understand how it could work.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `c++` so why the tag?

Comment: @Devolus because Juce is a C++ project which compiles C++ in Android